# Paypal redirect logging me out of my site?

Tags: session, laravel-4, paypal, payment

I have no idea if anyone experience this, i have a slight problem when redirecting from paypal to my site back....

I have a site built with angularjs + php in the backend of it, i log in to my site and everything is fine, When i try to do a recurring payments, it redirects to paypal, i accept the payments and such, when i come back to my site (review payment) i have in the url the payer id and token, which is exactly what i need.. but im not logged in anymore to my site.

The problem with this is, if i do reconnect to my site again, and do the same procedure, now it's all good...

What can be the cause of my site to log out the user when it redirect's back from somewhere, in this case, from paypal?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question and the potential answers depend upon how you are managing your user login sessions. You could be clearing a cookie somewhere, or failing to call the right framework piece in your handling of the returning user, or your return URL from PayPal might put you in a different subdomain that can't share your session cookie, or....

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at two requests from the browser to your website:
- the last one *before* redirection to PayPal
- the redirection from PayPal
Open the Network tab in FireBug or Developer Tools, depending on your browser, and examine the values sent in cookies.

1. Check if your browser accepts cookies (assuming it's cookie-based sessions you are using)
2. Make sure there is a cookie created by your PHP when you make the first one
3. Make sure it is still there, sent from the browser when you come back from PayPal
4. Make sure the values in the cookies (session ids) match
5. Also, that the server does not send a "set-cookie" header in the response to the second request

A "no" to any of the above opens a few more options to investigate, so start with these.